# External Style Sheet not working

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project for school (we have to code for a calculator), and we're using external CSS for the first time. I've been trying for an hour, but I guess my external CSS isn't linking properly? The calculator just shows up without any styling at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Crazy Calc</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>My Crazy Calculator<h1>
<form name="calc">
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input class="textfield" type="text" name="input" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="reset" value="clear" onclick="calc.input.value+='reset'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="M" onclick="calc.store.value=calc.input.value;calc.input.value=''"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="MR" onclick="calc.input.value+=calc.store.value"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="calc.input.value+='/'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="7" onclick="calc.input.value+='7'">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="8" onclick="calc.input.value+='8'">
    </td> 
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="9" onclick="calc.input.value+='9'">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="*" onclick="calc.input.value+='*'">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="4" onclick="calc.input.value+='4'">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="5" onclick="calc.input.value+='5'">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="6" onclick="calc.input.value+='6'">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="calc.input.value+='-'">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="calc.input.value+='1'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="calc.input.value+='2'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="calc.input.value+='3'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="calc.input.value+='+'"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input  type="button" value="0" onclick="calc.input.value+='0'"></td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="=" onclick="calc.input.value=eval(calc.input.value)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="calc.input.value+='.'"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="sin" onclick="calc.input.value=Math.sin(calc.input.value*Math.PI/180)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="cos" onclick="calc.input.value=Math.cos(calc.input.value*Math.PI/180)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="tan" onclick="calc.input.value=Math.tan(calc.input.value*Math.PI/180)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="|x|" onclick="calc.input.value=Math.abs(calc.input.value)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="log(x)" onclick="calc.input.value=Math.log(calc.input.value)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="sqrt(x)" onclick="calc.input.value=Math.sqrt(calc.input.value)"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="e^x" onclick="calc.input.value=Math.exp(calc.input.value)"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="store"></td>
</tr>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The style sheet:

```
  body {
       background-color: black; 
        }

    h1 {
       color:white;
       text-align:center;
       font-family:calibri;
     }

   table{
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       border:3px solid blue;
       border-radius:25px;
     }
```

Comment: Check the browser's developer tools to see what errors you're getting.

Comment: It should work: check the console (in Chrome on Windows Ctr shift I).

Comment: Directory of both files is same?

Comment: Chk browser console if directory not same it will give u 404

Comment: thanks, i'll try it now

Comment: it's giving me an error

Comment: and the error would be.....?

Comment: it's failing to load the external style sheet

Comment: If it is urgent, can you simply just put it in a style block in the html?

Comment: Are your HTML file and stylesheet in the same folder? Is the stylesheet on the server?

Comment: Your HTML files has several syntax errors. You should run it through a validator to fix them. But in a nutshell, your error boils down to either your stylesheet not being on the server, or the path to it being incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

1. if the style sheet file is in same folder, add a forward slash:
   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/calcstyle.css">`
2. the file name is usually case sensitive, so ensure you are using the exact same name. Also check for spaces in your code or file name.

Comment: a forward slash between text and css? so text\css?

Comment: in href property: href="/calcstyle.css"

Comment: still not working. i don't think chrome is finding my style sheet for some reason

Comment: right click on page and "View page Source", then hover your mouse pointer over "/calcstyle.css" and check the target on bottom-left corner of the page. is that right? does it show you the css content if you click on it?

Comment: all of the html? sure

Comment: so in your code it is "/style.css" but your original question and your style sheet file was supposed to be "/calcstyle.css"

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with what kind of platform you're using.

When I was using "wampserver" and PHP, I did it your way and of course it worked.

But now I'm using Visual Studio Code. I tried the same way, but it didn't work at all. The following is my link within the :

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/shop.css">
```

Here my shop.css file is in the "css" folder, which in turn is in the "public" folder. No matter what I did, it just didn't work.

Then I learned that I had to set the path in my app.js file in the following way:

```
       app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I'm not sure what kind of platform you're using, but I'm afraid that your problem is similar to mine.

This is just a reminder.

Hope it can be of any help.

Answer (score -1):

I incorrectly pointed out that the unclosed link element might be the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Crazy Calc</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calcstyle.css"/>
    </head>
```